# How to properly import WixBalExtension in wixproj file?

Tags: wix

I am trying to import the WixBalExtension.dll. I confirmed that the path is correct, but I'm running into the following error:

```
The extension 'Wix\WixBalExtension.dll' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'WixBalExtension, Version=3.0.0.0, Cul
       ture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ce35f76fcda82bad' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Excep
       tion from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
```

This is what my extensions look like in the wixproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Project.wxs" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixNetFxExtension.dll" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixUIExtension.dll" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixUtilExtension.dll" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixIIsExtension.dll" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixDependencyExtension.dll" />
    <WixExtension Include="$(Wix_Dir)\WixBalExtension.dll"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there something that I'm missing? The error isn't clear on whether it's a dependency missing or something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Strong name validation failed.` indicates you have a corrupt file. Try checking the digital signature in Explorer.